# Bootstrap - Image to gif to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am currently using bootstrap, html and css but is totally new to it all and really hope you can help. I am trying to change an image to a gif on hover and then to a modal when clicked on. This will be for a team page similar to www.electricpulp.com/about/.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<figure> 
    <div id="user-01" class="img-responsive figure-img img-fluid">
    </div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption"> 
    <b>Norman Coleman</b><br>Data Analyst</figcaption> 
    </figure>
```

**CSS**

```
#user-01 {
  background: url("../images/team/user-01.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-position: center;
  }

#user-01:hover {
  background: url("../images/team/giphy-01.gif") no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-position: center; }
```

I will need this for about 20 team members. I know there must be a shorter way of doing this (javascript or jquery), but for the life of me can't find anything online that works as intended.

Thanks in advance
Chrissie

Comment: Hi Chrissie, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer
http://activelab.io/tutorials/create-a-css-card-flip-effect-on-hover  and https://codepen.io/darkwing/pen/bCali

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

For a cleaner and DRY CSS file, you should use the cascading feature of CSS.
Use a class for user elements with all the common styles:

```
.user {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Use IDs for background images only:

```
#user-01 {
  background: url("../images/team/user-01.jpg") no-repeat;
}

#user-01:hover {
  background: url("../images/team/giphy-01.gif") no-repeat;
}
```

For opening a modal in Bootstrap add this parameters to the DIV with user class:

```
<div id="user-01" class="img-responsive figure-img img-fluid user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></div>
```

And use this code for modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[more info on modals](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much Saeed. I will definitely use the DRY approach in the future. For some reason the modal doesn't want to launch. As soon as the image turns into a gif the modal doesn't work.

Comment: Somehow there was a problem with my bootstrap files. All sorted now. Thanks for the help it works perfectly.